# Best way to store hierarchical tags

Tags: database-design, language-agnostic, architecture, data-structures

I have a list, where each list entry is tagged with multiple tags. Each tag can also have child tags. Every entry in the list can have more than one tags.

For example, a list entry that talks about cars can have tags called "cars", "vehicles", "ferrari".

I should be able to view a hierarchy of tags, like shown below. Also, there should be no limit to number of tags per entry, and also how deep the tags can go.

How do I store this data? I am open to using any type of DBMS.

[image]

Comment: What about a NoSQL DataBase?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151 (not a duplicate, since the current question is also open to NoSQL solutions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naive approach would be a parent / child solution, but it's very difficult to write efficient queries with this data model.

[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) is a pretty good article about hierarchical data structures. I suppose most of it can be applied to other database systems, too.

Comment: The idea is neat but I wonder how easy would it be if the entire hierarchy is evolving with time.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the simplest way for any database:
`tag (id, name, parent_id)`, where `parent_id` refers to `id` of the parent tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 sources of data, but, seems you are mixing both.

One data is your list entries, that seems to be lineal, non hierarchical.

For example, a list of movies.

The other source of data, its a collection of hierarchical data ("tags catalog").

For example a list of movie styles.

```
+---Styles
  +---Comedy
    +---KidsComedy
    +---SomeComedy
    +---LOLComedy
  +---Action
    +---SomeAction
    +---GrabYourCouchSofaAction
  +---Drama
    +---SomeDrama
    +---LotsOfTearsDrama
    +---EvenToughGuysWillCryDrama
  +---Horror
    +---SoftHorror
    +---HardHorror
    +---Gore
  +---SciFi
```

Each movie can be associated with several movie styles:

- "StarWars:The Phantom Menace": {"SciFi,"SomeDrama","SoftHorror","SomeAction"}
- "StarTrek:First Contact": {"SciFi,"SomeDrama","SomeComedy"}

In terms of Database design, you should have unleast 3 tables or Entity Objects:

- List Entries = {ListEntryID, ListEntryTitle, ...}
- Movie Genres Tags / Styles = {TagID, TagTitle, ...}
- Styles For Movie = {TagForListEntryID, ListEntryID, TagID, ...}

Good Luck.

Comment: Yes. Thank You for taking time to understand my question. Sorry if it wasn't clear earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use the XML format which will help you in storing the nodes as parent and child
It can have n number of nodes and easy to form and handle.
Note: The below one is just an example, So by this way you can handle the data.

```
<Menu>
  <Menuitem1>
      <submenu1>
         <submenu1>
            <submenu1.1/> 
          </submenu1>        
      </submenu1>
  </Menuitem1>

  <Menuitem1>
      <submenu1>
      </submenu1>
  </Menuitem1>
</Menu>
```

I think this may help you.

Comment: How do I link each item to an entry in the list? I need to store the list entries too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach the problem:First, I will draw a domain model. In your case it looks like:

```
List(1)----contains----(0..*)-->ListItem
ListItem(0..1)----hasTags--(0..*)-->Tag
Tag(0..1)-----hasSubTags---(0..*)-->Tag
```

This makes the problem explicit leaving no room for doubts.

Now, translate this to a data-model. This is pretty straightforward: for each relation introduce suitable PrimaryKey-ForeignKey mappings.Many-to-Many relations should be split into two 1-M relations using a new table in between.

The data-model you have at this stage should be functionally correct, but could have performance issues. Now is the time for you to focus on the queries that you would want and optimize the table structure accordingly.

(Another similar refinement trip starting from the domain model will give you the design for the final class model as well)

Hope this approach helps.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583812/mysql-operating-hierarchical-data/6802687#6802687). I store parents for all the levels - the tree building and querying all descendants is extremely easy.